# Wait By Text Attribute inside a Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Journey where it creates Custom Object record using Object Activity in Salesforce. There is a Activity object in Salesforce which is related to this Custom object in Salesforce Sales Cloud.

Sales Rep will call the phone no on the Custom Object record and enter an activity for the same.

We are synchronizing the Custom object back to Marketing Cloud using an Automation.There is a field on the Custom object populated when an Activity is entered for that in Salesforce Sales Cloud. This field is also synchronized.

For example:

CustomObject_DE

Contact Key Custom Object 1 Record     ActivityDonebySalesRep

12345        Salesforce 18 digit ID     No
123456        Salesforce 18 digit ID    Yes

If ActivityDonebySalesRep is No then the Journey should wait based on this attribute(until this field is populated in CustomObject_DE) the second Custom Object record should not be populated in Salesforce from the Journey.

Wait by Attribute is based of a Date field in Marketing Cloud. Is there a way to achieve this use case from Journey.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no possibility to wait until a value is changed within a journey. You could however create a second journey, that uses a Salesforce data event as an entry source and listens to the field change. Another option is running a scheduled automation that checks your criteria via a SQL query based on the synchronized data extension of your custom object and injects your audience into the second journey.

**Further reading:**

- [The Salesforce Data Event - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_salesforce_data_event.htm&type=5)
- [SQL Query Activity - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)

Comment: But unfortunately we need to close the two custom object records after a certain wait period in the Journey. If i have a second journey then i will not be able to close the first custom object record created in the first journey.

Comment: As the objects are connected in SFDC this should also work within a second journey. However, this seems to be a more appropriate use case for a trigger in SFDC anyways. Nonetheless, my answer should be correct, as waiting within a journey won't work as there is no such activity unfortunately. Hope this helps